# Considere the following function $f$ defined by $ f(x, y)=ln^2(y + x^2)+\sqrt{x}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Considere the following function $f$ defined by $$ f(x, y)=ln^2(y + x^2)+\sqrt{x}$$

Start at the point $(1, 0)$. Find the minimum of $f$ in the direction (line) $(1, 2)$ using
the Golden-Section line-search algorithm with interval $[0, 1]$. Stop when the length of
the interval is less than $0.15$. Note: the interval could be described by the parameter $t$,
and a point along the direction $(1, 2)$ can be expressed as $(1, 0) + t(1, 2)$

In this case the function is a two variables function, how can I continue? Do I need a region for the values of $x$ and $y$? In a variable the idea is to extract regions depending on the product of the images of the points.

Comment: It's not a 2D region, it's 1D; you're just putting $y=2x$ to create a function of a single variable. Then you can proceed with the golden section search.

Comment: But why $y=2x$?

Comment: They mean $y=2(x-1)$ - the point being one of the variables has effectively been substituted away. However doing this substitution directly would not be good because of how you have defined arc length. A $t$ interval of $[0,1]$ is $\sqrt{5}$ times the length of an $x$ interval of $[0,1]$

Comment: @NinadMunshi you're right, that is what I meant! The interval issue is only a scale factor, which is easy enough to apply.